# Set of httpheaders required on API method

Tags: .net, rest

In my .NET 7 API controllers I have a few methods that all require the same set of headers. Around 4 or 5.
Instead of adding them in each every method on several controllers, is there a way to add use something like a custom implementation of middleware or attribute on the method?
Possibly with some extensions to extract them again, and perhaps combine them in one specific class. Thoughts?

[image: headers]